# Advice on how to simplify things for user

Tags: content-management-system

I'm making a very simple cms for a client. I am working on adding/editing articles and i wanted advice on how to make it as simple as possible for him to add images to an article. I was thinking of using some sort of bbcode [img] [/img] Any suggestions ? 
*I'm using codeigniter as a framework

Answer (score 0):

what are you coding in? I have used FreeTextBox.com and it has a built in image manager that is quite simple to use.

Comment: I'm using codeigniter as a framework, do you think there are any problems importing freetextbox ?

Comment: I would just go with ckEdit and its built in Image management tools